# Let $U(n)$ be the group of units in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. If $n>2$, prove that there's an element in $k$ in $U(n)$ such that $k^2=1$ and $k \neq 1$

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

Title says it all. I have no idea how to go about this proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do you know the two solutions of $x^2=1$ in $\mathbf Z$?

Comment: looking at a few tables of this group, it appears that k=n-1 is when this phenomenon occurs

Comment: Exactly! Can you prove that $(n-1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod n$? Then, can you prove that $1 \not\equiv n-1 \mod n$? (Remark that $n-1 = -1$ in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$)

Comment: Let's see: (n-1)^2 - 1 = np, for some integer p. Which then is n^2-2n=np, and n-2=p, which is also an integer, so (n-1)^2=1mod(n) is true. Then with the next expression, we have 1-(n-1) = np, which is 2-n=np, then 2/n - 1 = p, and since n>2, this value isn't an integer and therefore 1=/=n-1mod(n).

is that the whole proof?

Comment: @Mik I think you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $gcd(n-1,n)=1$, therefore $n-1\in U(n)$. If we multiply $n-1$ by itself we get,

$$(n-1)^2\equiv n^2-2n+1\equiv 1\, (mod\,n)$$

On the other hand, if  $n-1\equiv 1\, (mod \,n)\Leftrightarrow -1\equiv 1\,(mod\, n)\Leftrightarrow 0\equiv 2\,(mod\,n)$. And that is only possible if $n=2$ but, by hypothesis, $n>2$, hence $n-1 \not\equiv 1\,(mod\,n)$.